# WPF MVVM with data templates for base/derived classes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance, mvvm

I want to do something like that:

I have a base class **VerticalConnectorViewModel** and a derived class **StairsViewModel**.
I use WPF data templates to define a view for those objects.
For example my base class is assigned like this (inside the **UserControl.Resources**:

```
<!-- Define a data-template for the 'VerticalConnectorViewModel' class. This generates the UI for each node. -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:VerticalConnectorViewModel}">
    <network:VerticalConnectorView></network:VerticalConnectorView>
</DataTemplate>
<!-- Define a data-template for the 'StairsViewModel' class. This generates the UI for each node. -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:StairsViewModel}">
    <network:StairsView></network:StairsView>
</DataTemplate>
```

I have created two different Usercontrols, namely the 'network:VerticalConnectorView' and the 'network:StairsView'. Both look similar, except for some additional elements for the latter.

My **VerticalConnectorView.xaml** file looks like this (but is not really important here I think):

```
<UserControl x:Class="NetworkUI.VerticalConnectorView"
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                     xmlns:network="clr-namespace:NetworkUI"
                     mc:Ignorable="d" 
                     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <StackPanel>
            <network:NodeView x:Name="nodeView"></network:NodeView>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <StackPanel Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="sharedDescription" Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <network:EditableTextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Type" FontSize="10" IsEditable="False"></network:EditableTextBlock>
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedItem="{Binding Type}" ItemsSource="{Binding TypeValues}"></ComboBox>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <StackPanel Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="sharedDescription" Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <network:EditableTextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Placement" FontSize="10" IsEditable="False"></network:EditableTextBlock>
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedItem="{Binding Placement}" ItemsSource="{Binding PlacementValues}"></ComboBox>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

There are two ComboBox elements. The first one lets you select 'Random', 'Stairs', 'Elevator or 'Escalator'. Now, what I want to do, is if one selects 'Stairs' I want to change my ViewModel from VerticalConnectionViewModel to StairsViewModel (and let the WPF use the other View).

Since I use a Collection for all my ViewModels I already tried to use the **SelectionChanged** event for the removal of the old ViewModel and the addition of the new one (instance of a different class), but that didn't work either.

Is this possible or should I rethink my approach? I know I can e.g. use only one class and update the UI for different selected values, but should I really add all possible values to my base-class? E.g. it makes no sense to have a **StairsType** property if the type of the VerticalConnector is set to 'Elevator', right?

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want to change the type of the selected object based on user selection, right? i.e. you have a collection bound to UI which by default is of type model:VerticalConnectorViewModel then user can select 'Stairs' and then that type should change to model:StairsViewModel

Comment: My DataContext of the View is my ViewModel. The View is created based on the Datatemplate (first code-part). In the view, I can change the "type", and if I select "Stairs" I want my ViewModel to change to my derived class and see the View get updated, too

Comment: when the user changes to 'Stairs' then the viewmodel can insert a new entry in the collection at same place and then if the collection is observablecollection it will automatically update bound item on view which will resolve what has to be displayed based on datatemplate

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: Hi, yes, I did solve it! I remove my ViewModel from the Collection and add the new one to it! It works fine now! I tried that before and it didn't work, but now everything is ok! Idk why it didn't work at first.

Comment: Strange... well as long as it works :) maybe binding update was a issue